# Как совместить bootstrap и ie8

Tags: bootstrap, internet-explorer, html, javascript, css

Только начинаю разбираться с ним, но там написано что якобы подключив respond.js. В ie 8 будет отображаться нормальной. Я скачал шаблон, там прописана эта строчка. Вот мой код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper container">
    <div class="header">    
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <a href="/"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Whitesquare logo"></a>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="news"><a href="/about/">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="/price/">Price</a></li>
                <li><a href="/services/">Services</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="/schedule/">Schedule</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contacts/">Contacts</a></li>      
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

В гугле хроме, моззиле ситуация такая, что на панели находится логотип и рядом с ним горизонтальное меню. В ие8 ничем подобным не пахнет. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить вот эти строки

```
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
```

На локальные копии файлов (их можно скачать)

```
 <script src="~/RelativePath/html5shiv.js"></script>
 <script src="~/RelativePath/respond.min.js"></script>
```

Если это не помогло попробуйте посмотреть и повторить шаги описанные тут [bootstrap 3 supporting internet explorer 8 and 9](http://www.joostrap.com/blog/bootstrap-3-supporting-internet-explorer-8-and-9)
или тут [ie8 issue with twitter bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3)

P.S. скажите а нельзя пользователю вывести сообщение мол "обновите браузер и т.д." или такое требование проекта? Ведь уже 11-ая верия IE вышла ... :-)

**Дополнение (Update)**

---

Попробуйте также

- Добавить теги

  > ```
  > <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  > <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  > ```
- Скрипты (которые ниже) сразу после
  секции с CSS

> ```
> <!--[if lt IE 9]>  
>      <script src="~/RelativePath/html5shiv.js"></script>
>      <script src="~/RelativePath/respond.min.js"></script>
> <![endif]-->
> ```

- Поменяйте следующий код с

> ```
> <nav class="navbar" role="navigation"></nav>
> ```

на

> ```
> <header class="navbar" role="navigation"></header>
> ```

Comment: у меня такая же проблема на сайте jff.by
Я прочитал представленные вами материалы, но это не помогло. у меня в IE 8 показывает мобильную версию сайта, растянутую на весь экран.Никак не могу найти как это поправить

Comment: @cema93 я обновил свой ответ, надеюсь это поможет, если нет то даже не знаю в чем может быть дело.

Comment: @pvkovalev, ваш вариант полностью рабочий.

Comment: Мне что бы бутстрап коректно работал под ie8 пришлось `<nav>` заменить не на `<header>`, а на `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

Хочу сказать, что у меня все заработало после

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```